# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/util/DerValue

Tags: java, encryption, websphere

My application is up on websphere and i keep seeing this error , due to which it sometime triggers 500 internal server error.

The application needs 256 bit encryption and java by default does not provide the same. So i have used Sun JCE which is creating this problem in websphere.

Answer (score 1):

Found something : looks like The 'sun/security/util/DerValue' is a sun class,which is not included in the IBM JDK. IBM does not support problems with 3rd party JSSE or JCE providers. Only the IBM JSSE and JCE providers are supported.

I used the IBM JCE to resolve this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you need stronger encryption you need to download and install unrestricted policy files as shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz6vJCqvDrc). You can download these files from [here](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/preLogin.do?source=jcesdk).